# Unfielded Solr search in nested documents

Tags: solr

I want to provide an "unfielded search" in nested Solr documents with a lot of fields in parents and childs.

A user should only specify a couple of search terms. Possible results should contain all these terms in

- a parent or
- one child or
- a parent and one child

This means that term matches should'nt be distributed over a couple of childs.

The number of fields to search is variable and depend on a selected view (might be only parent fields or parent and child fields).

Example:

If the following nested document is indexed:

```
[
  {
    "title": "document 1",
    "text": "example doc text a",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "childTitle": "s1a",
        "childText": "child tok1a",
        "type": "child",
        "id": "1_a"
      },
      {
        "childTitle": "s1b",
        "childText": "child tok1b",
        "type": "child",
        "id": "1_b"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parent",
    "id": "1"
  }
]
```

then these queries should match the document:

- 1
- 1 a
- s1a child tok1a
- document s1a
- document 1 a s1b tok1b

But the queries listed below should not match the document:

- s1a tok1b
- document 1 a tok1a s1b

I've tried with filter queries for each search term on a view with title and childTitle, e.g.

```
query: document s1a
fq=title:document {!parent which="type:parent"}childTitle:document
fq=title:s1a {!parent which="type:parent"}childTitle:s1a

query: s1a s1b
fq=title:s1a {!parent which="type:parent"}childTitle:s1a
fq=title:s1b {!parent which="type:parent"}childTitle:s1b
```

The second query delivers the document as hit, but the matching terms are distributed over 2 childs and that breaks the requirements.

Is there any way to realize this with Solr?

Comment: First suggestion would be to index these as single documents instead of parent/child relationships. That will make it far easier to get the query profile you're looking for.

Comment: That's an option of course. But in case of more than one child type there would a combinatorial explosion of records. Furthermore these records have to be handled in a result list of a search. If no tokens are matching in a child, then one record would be enough. This might be solved with grouping of size 1. But token matches in the childs are the next problem if more than one child is matching.